# Random word generator - IOS development

Tags: ios, random, cpu-word, generator

I'm developing a app where people must click on a button and then the label show a random word.

I can use a switch statement, but the app must have more than 50 words, so to write the switch statement is a lot of work and not very useful.

Do someone have a solution?

Comment: Why not use an array??  This is pretty much exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use an array, and a random number generator.

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
[myLabel setText:[myArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([myArray count])]];
```

This should be enough to nudge you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a switch. Use An array with the fifty items intitalised and use a random number generator to get an random index in the array, which will return a random word.......